# Can't reinstall Ubuntu after multiple times (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, crash

So I decided to reinstall Ubuntu from zero since I had some issues, then during the first [failed] reinstallation, the PC couldn't boot, so decided to reinstall it a second time, the installer crashed. When trying to install a third time I noticed I got this http://i.imgsafe.org/e005051be7.jpg and couldn't do much. So I my hard-drive to none format and then tried to reinstall Ubuntu, but it crashed again! It says
"The system log from your installation contains an error. The specific error commonly occurs when there is an issue with the disk to which you are trying to install Ubuntu. It is recommended that you back up important data on your disk and investigate the situation. Measures you might take include cehchking [nice spelling] cable comnections for your disks and using software tools to investigate health of your hardware"
 Any idea why? Any idea if it is due to my hardware or to the installation media?

Anyway, thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check would be the disk integrity. Use a tool like "crystal disk info" from a windows machine and see what it says regarding the hard drive. If the drive is bad, I recommend getting a new one. If it is fine, then I would consider bad SATA cables or installation media. Bad cables and pins are rare (unless you have been removing the hard drive rather rough) but is still possible. You will rarely get this error from a bad installation media but it is possible as well.